# Did Holdo know about Crait?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

> In The Last Jedi, the resistance fleet, seemingly about to be destroyed, fortuitously comes across the planet Crait, and Leia "reveals" a plan to stealth down to the planet to escape.  This is news to the audience, who thus far knew that Admiral Holdo's plan was... to just keep running until they died?

...or was it?

**Did Vice Admiral Holdo know about the presence of Crait and/or intend to go there all along?**

Answers directly from the movie are preferable, but other canon material is also acceptable.

<s>Incidentally, if she **did** know about Crait, why was this information not shared with the rest of the resistance command?</s>  Corollary question discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176610/why-wasnt-poe-told-about-holdos-plan), though I would prefer an explanation from canon material instead of speculation.

Comment: I think she did know. This is an aspect of Holdo's personality. She is very competent (obviously), but likes to play her cards close to her chest. For example, she didn't tell most people the details of her plan for the escape pods (even when confronted with mutiny), and I think Leia expressed annoyance with how Holdo talked in riddles in some written work. Strictly speaking, she didn't need to share any information at that point, even with the command, since she was in charge. It might have been a good idea, but it appears that such is simply how she does things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why wasn't Poe told about Holdo's plan?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176610/why-wasnt-poe-told-about-holdos-plan)

Comment: The linked question assumes that Holdo knew about Crait, I am asking if that was actually the case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both Leia and Holdo knew where they were going when they executed their jump. Leia had info about a last-ditch, middle-of-nowhere base that they could use and Holdo must have known about their destination since Leia spent much of their journey unconscious.

The film's [Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) is very clear on who knew what and how.

> THE LAST GASP of hope for the Resistance is the otherwise uninviting
>   mineral planet of Crait, tucked in a remote sector of the Outer Rim
>   Territories. **This has been Leia Organa *and Amilyn Holdo's* secret
>   endgame - bunkering down on a former rebel world that had fallen off
>   most modern starcharts.** The Resistance's penchant for using old
>   rebel-era caches and facilities is part of Leia's strategy, for she
>   alone has a store of navigational information from the early days or
>   the Rebellion that she has never shared.

Comment: You've been cashing in on these Visual Dictionary answers Valorum :D I bought it specifically to answer SE questions but you're beating me to 'em all

Comment: @Allball103 - You should invest in a decent hand-scanner and a copy of ABBYY Finereader to OCR the images into text.

Comment: it's not worth it I can't compete with the master

Comment: ..."or she alone has a store of navigational information from the early days or the Rebellion that she has never shared." - hope she info dumps that to somebody or something before Ep9

Comment: @NKCampbell - I'm sure it's in R2-D2's memory somewhere.