# Is Crait a deus ex machina?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, plot-device

*Note: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177626/did-holdo-know-about-crait)! This is a more general question which links to what is the accepted answer to that one and clearly says it doesn't solve the problem. Additionally, whether Holdo knew about Crait while she was in command is not really relevant here, as there was only one direction of travel anyway.*

Near the beginning of The Last Jedi, the Resistance jumps into hyperspace to get away from the First Order. It seems reasonable to assume they jumped to a random, unpredictable location in deep space to lose the First Order and regroup. There seems to be no plan for further action at this point. These points are evidenced by the following conversation:

> FINN: We're really nowhere.
>
> [...]
>
> FINN: Alright, so until she gets back, what's the plan?
>
> LEIA: We need to find a new base.

Immediately after, First Order ships catch up. As a result of the confrontation, there's only one thing the Resistance can do: speed away from the enemy ships using their standard engines.

The main premise of the movie is the desperate chase in space, and the feeling of hopelessness coming from the fact the Resistance apparently has nowhere to run. So the revelation that there was actually an abandoned Rebel base, with anti-orbital bombardment shields, gigantic blast doors and powerful antennas, exactly on their course, within 24 hours of sublight travel, comes as a complete deus ex machina.

The chances of this happening are mindbogglingly small, so it seems it must have been the plan all along. This is what the Visual Dictionary states (taken from [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/177642/95369)):

> THE LAST GASP of hope for the Resistance is the otherwise uninviting
>   mineral planet of Crait, tucked in a remote sector of the Outer Rim
>   Territories. **This has been Leia Organa *and Amilyn Holdo's* secret
>   endgame - bunkering down on a former rebel world that had fallen off
>   most modern starcharts.** The Resistance's penchant for using old
>   rebel-era caches and facilities is part of Leia's strategy, for she
>   alone has a store of navigational information from the early days or
>   the Rebellion that she has never shared.

But this just raises more questions:

- If they aimed for Crait, why did they exit hyperspace so far away from the planet, especially as they barely had enough fuel to actually reach it?
- Why did Leia say "We need to find a new base" if they already travelled to one?

And there's the fact that once First Order ships appeared, there was only one direction of travel available. It's still extremely lucky that Crait was exactly there...

**Is there any explanation for this?**

Comment: Same reason the *Falcon* just happened to be within reach of Cloud City when the hyperdrive failed in ESB?  Apparently, a Galaxy Far Far Away just isn't as big as you might expect.

Comment: `It seems reasonable to assume they jumped to a random...location` There's your first assumption.

Comment: Related: [Why wasn't Poe told about Holdo's plan?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176610/21267)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, this is a more general question that builds upon the question link and clearly says the answer to that one is not enough!

Comment: If you don't like that answers on the dupe, you can always make comments, post a bounty or answer it yourself.

Comment: It's not reasonable to assume they jumped blindly when all the evidence suggests that Crait was their intended destination.

Comment: @Möoz The question clearly says that this assumption is apparently false because of what the Visual Dictionary states. The assumption is stated because it's what is suggested by the movie and what makes Crait feel like a deus ex machina.

Comment: @Valorum The accepted answer on the dupe answers the question well — it confirms that Holdo knew about Crait according to canon sources. However, Holdo knowing or not knowing about Crait is not relevant to my question, because she couldn't have done much about the direction of travel anyway.

Comment: Is it a deus ex machina? No. It's a reveal. It's also a reveal (to Poe)  in-universe

Comment: @Valorum I think a reveal still counts as a deus ex machina if a reveal is extremely implausible, and I list questions which would need to be answered before classifying the reveal as plausible in my opinion. A full "no" answer should plausibly answer those, I think.

Comment: The Visual Dictionary makes it clear Crait was always the plan, so the only real questions are why they jumped so far out and why they jumped with barely enough fuel to reach the planet. Perhaps they jumped so far out so they could approach with caution (just because the planet's uncharted, doesn't mean it's not subsequently been occupied by hostile forces). As for the fuel question, they were under attack and left with the resources they could muster, maybe the plan was to redistribute fuel/personnel on arrival but the First Order appeared and made that impossible.

Comment: @delinear - My feeling is that because it's a poorly charted system, they jumped out *near* Crait, then  located it and had to motor the rest of the way in. If it was a well mapped, high-traffic system like Coruscant they could have presumably popped out of hyperspace practically on  top of it.

Comment: @Valorum great point! Presumably the further out they are when they arrive, the less likely they are to hit a major planetary body or emerge in the middle of an asteroid field :)